# Overriding Equality Operators

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, equals, gethashcode

I've implemented a class that overloads the `==` and `!=` operators.

This seems to work fine; however, I get the warning `'type' defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.Equals(object o)`.

Okay, so I implemented Equals. But now I get the warning `'type' defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.GetHashCode()`.

Does this end at some point? Or have I wandered into a never-ending trail of requirements just because I want to overload `==` and `!=`?

Comment: Quick terminology correction: you don't *override* operators - you *overload* them.

Comment: When you override `Equals`, you need to override `GetHashCode` as well, as it will check equality based on a hash function.

Comment: @IgorisAzanovas No, Equals will not check equality based on a hash function (unless you overload it and specifically code it that way). The hash function is there for supporting hashed collections and is not expected to generate a unique value, only one that ideally will be infrequently used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does this end at some point?

Yes, once you implement [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) it will end. [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/) has [blogged about its importance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx). All I can do is suggest you to read and trust him :-)

Comment: Okay, so can anyone point to a good algorithm that takes converts an integer value to a reasonable hash value?

Comment: @Darin why do we need to override object.equals() when we just overload "==" operator?

Comment: @Jonathon: if your only identifying information is an `int`, the built-in `int` type uses itself as its hash value. If it's good enough for them...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will end when you override `GetHashCode`.

When implementing equality operators, and furthermore `Equals`, it is the responsibility of the programmer to provide an implementation to deliver a custom hash code for that type.

See [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx) for details.